# Authorize.Net SIM method with Velocity payment gateway

Tags: velocity, authorize.net

I am integrating velocity through Authorize.net SIM method using https://nabvelocity.com/solutions/checkout/e-commerce-integration/authorize/

I have created form with the url mentioned in the link but everytime it gives an error that terminal profile id is required.
From where I have to pass the ID?

**This is the code**

```
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
include 'vendor/authorizenet/authorizenet/lib/AuthorizeNetSIM.php';
?>
<form method="post" action="https://api.cert.nabcommerce.com/VGate/1.0/AuthorizeNet/SimContainer.aspx">
    <?php
    $amount = "9.99";
    $fp_sequence = "123";
    $time = time();
    $api_login = 'EPX Retail Test';
    $transaction_key = '8D9DE00001';
    $fingerprint = AuthorizeNetSIM_Form::getFingerprint($api_login, $transaction_key, $amount, $fp_sequence, $time);
    $sim = new AuthorizeNetSIM_Form(
        array(

            'x_amount' => $amount,
            'x_fp_sequence' => $fp_sequence,
            'x_fp_hash' => $fingerprint,
            'x_fp_timestamp' => $time,
            'x_relay_response' => "FALSE",
            'x_login' => $api_login,
            "x_type" => "AUTH_CAPTURE",
            "x_method" => "CC",
            "x_card_num" => '4242424242424242',
            "x_exp_date" => '12/22',
            "x_description" => "Live Transaction",
            "x_card_code" => '123',
            "x_first_name" => 'anamica',
            "x_address" => 'demo',
            "x_city" => 'delhi',
            "x_state" => 'delhi',
            "x_zip" => '110045',
            "x_country" => 'India',
        )
    );
    echo $sim->getHiddenFieldString(); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Buy Now" data>
</form>
```

Getting error terminal profile id required on this URL

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide sample code snippets that cause the problem. What exact error do you get? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to as a good question.

Comment: Posting my code in next comment

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a coding issue. This is a setup issue. Your Authorize.Net account is setup to be Card Present instead of Card Not Present. As a result it is expecting information from the credit card reader that you obviously are not using. You need to contact Authorize.Net support and have them correct your account setup.